# Unitary representations of $SL(2,Z_n)$ and $SL(3,Z_n)$

Tags: representation-theory, modular-forms

I would like to ask "is there a classification of unitary irreducible representations of $SL(2,Z_n)$ and or $SL(2,Z)$?"

Also, is there a classification of unitary irreducible representations of $SL(3,Z_n)$?

Here $Z_n=Z/nZ$.

Comment: Is $Z_n$ the ring $\mathbb Z/(n)$?

Comment: If so, that group is a direct product of subgroups of the form $SL(2,Z/(p^r))$ for various primes, and the representations of these are well known (by those who know them, at least)

Comment: For finite groups there is no need to specify that the representarions are unitary; an irreducible representation has an essentially unique unitary structure.

Comment: Yes $Z_n$ is $Z/(n)$. Is it also true that $SL(3,Z/(n))$ is a direct product of  subgroups of the form $SL(3,Z/(p^r))$  for various primes?